# What's the best model to analyze inflation seasonal adjustment with R?

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity, seasonality

Please, put in R the following structure:

```
infl <- structure(list(infl = c(91.37, 91.8, 92.14, 92.65, 93.08, 93.17, 
93.08, 93.08, 93.34, 93.25, 93.17, 93.25, 93.59, 93.76, 94.27, 
94.7, 94.87, 94.79, 94.62, 94.7, 95.04, 95.21, 95.13, 95.3, 95.13, 
95.55, 95.98, 96.15, 96.07, 96.15, 95.98, 96.15, 96.49, 96.58, 
96.58, 96.92, 96.58, 96.83, 97.35, 97.86, 98.11, 98.2, 97.94, 
98.2, 98.28, 98.71, 98.63, 98.88, 98.2, 98.54, 99.31, 99.73, 
99.99, 100.08, 99.99, 100.25, 100.67, 100.93, 100.67, 101.1, 
100.62, 100.91, 101.47, 102.16, 102.44, 102.51, 102.36, 102.46, 
102.48, 102.51, 102.55, 102.96, 102.38, 102.7, 103.39, 104.05, 
104.31, 104.41, 104.14, 104.19, 104.59, 105.12, 105.69, 106.12, 
105.67, 106.04, 107.11, 107.46, 108.14, 108.54, 108.38, 108.22, 
108.42, 108.45, 107.9, 107.75, 106.82, 107.26, 107.66, 108.04, 
108.1, 108.27, 107.51, 107.89, 107.91, 108.17, 108.28, 108.61, 
107.75, 108.02, 109.09, 109.58, 109.71, 109.7, 109.32, 109.54, 
109.77, 110.15, 110.27, 110.93, 110.11, 110.57, 112.11, 112.75, 
112.74, 112.75, 112.03, 112.23, 113.08, 113.44, 113.54, 113.91, 
112.96, 113.53, 115.03, 115.56, 115.38, 115.29, 114.65, 115.1, 
115.97)), .Names = "infl", row.names = c("2001-01-31 00:00:00", 
"2001-02-28 00:00:00", "2001-03-31 01:00:00", "2001-04-30 01:00:00", 
"2001-05-31 01:00:00", "2001-06-30 01:00:00", "2001-07-31 01:00:00", 
"2001-08-31 01:00:00", "2001-09-30 01:00:00", "2001-10-31 00:00:00", 
"2001-11-30 00:00:00", "2001-12-31 00:00:00", "2002-01-31 00:00:00", 
"2002-02-28 00:00:00", "2002-03-31 00:00:00", "2002-04-30 01:00:00", 
"2002-05-31 01:00:00", "2002-06-30 01:00:00", "2002-07-31 01:00:00", 
"2002-08-31 01:00:00", "2002-09-30 01:00:00", "2002-10-31 00:00:00", 
"2002-11-30 00:00:00", "2002-12-31 00:00:00", "2003-01-31 00:00:00", 
"2003-02-28 00:00:00", "2003-03-31 01:00:00", "2003-04-30 01:00:00", 
"2003-05-31 01:00:00", "2003-06-30 01:00:00", "2003-07-31 01:00:00", 
"2003-08-31 01:00:00", "2003-09-30 01:00:00", "2003-10-31 00:00:00", 
"2003-11-30 00:00:00", "2003-12-31 00:00:00", "2004-01-31 00:00:00", 
"2004-02-29 00:00:00", "2004-03-31 01:00:00", "2004-04-30 01:00:00", 
"2004-05-31 01:00:00", "2004-06-30 01:00:00", "2004-07-31 01:00:00", 
"2004-08-31 01:00:00", "2004-09-30 01:00:00", "2004-10-31 01:00:00", 
"2004-11-30 00:00:00", "2004-12-31 00:00:00", "2005-01-31 00:00:00", 
"2005-02-28 00:00:00", "2005-03-31 01:00:00", "2005-04-30 01:00:00", 
"2005-05-31 01:00:00", "2005-06-30 01:00:00", "2005-07-31 01:00:00", 
"2005-08-31 01:00:00", "2005-09-30 01:00:00", "2005-10-31 00:00:00", 
"2005-11-30 00:00:00", "2005-12-31 00:00:00", "2006-01-31 00:00:00", 
"2006-02-28 00:00:00", "2006-03-31 01:00:00", "2006-04-30 01:00:00", 
"2006-05-31 01:00:00", "2006-06-30 01:00:00", "2006-07-31 01:00:00", 
"2006-08-31 01:00:00", "2006-09-30 01:00:00", "2006-10-31 00:00:00", 
"2006-11-30 00:00:00", "2006-12-31 00:00:00", "2007-01-31 00:00:00", 
"2007-02-28 00:00:00", "2007-03-31 01:00:00", "2007-04-30 01:00:00", 
"2007-05-31 01:00:00", "2007-06-30 01:00:00", "2007-07-31 01:00:00", 
"2007-08-31 01:00:00", "2007-09-30 01:00:00", "2007-10-31 00:00:00", 
"2007-11-30 00:00:00", "2007-12-31 00:00:00", "2008-01-31 00:00:00", 
"2008-02-29 00:00:00", "2008-03-31 01:00:00", "2008-04-30 01:00:00", 
"2008-05-31 01:00:00", "2008-06-30 01:00:00", "2008-07-31 01:00:00", 
"2008-08-31 01:00:00", "2008-09-30 01:00:00", "2008-10-31 00:00:00", 
"2008-11-30 00:00:00", "2008-12-31 00:00:00", "2009-01-31 00:00:00", 
"2009-02-28 00:00:00", "2009-03-31 01:00:00", "2009-04-30 01:00:00", 
"2009-05-31 01:00:00", "2009-06-30 01:00:00", "2009-07-31 01:00:00", 
"2009-08-31 01:00:00", "2009-09-30 01:00:00", "2009-10-31 00:00:00", 
"2009-11-30 00:00:00", "2009-12-31 00:00:00", "2010-01-31 00:00:00", 
"2010-02-28 00:00:00", "2010-03-31 01:00:00", "2010-04-30 01:00:00", 
"2010-05-31 01:00:00", "2010-06-30 01:00:00", "2010-07-31 01:00:00", 
"2010-08-31 01:00:00", "2010-09-30 01:00:00", "2010-10-31 01:00:00", 
"2010-11-30 00:00:00", "2010-12-31 00:00:00", "2011-01-31 00:00:00", 
"2011-02-28 00:00:00", "2011-03-31 01:00:00", "2011-04-30 01:00:00", 
"2011-05-31 01:00:00", "2011-06-30 01:00:00", "2011-07-31 01:00:00", 
"2011-08-31 01:00:00", "2011-09-30 01:00:00", "2011-10-31 00:00:00", 
"2011-11-30 00:00:00", "2011-12-31 00:00:00", "2012-01-31 00:00:00", 
"2012-02-29 00:00:00", "2012-03-31 01:00:00", "2012-04-30 01:00:00", 
"2012-05-31 01:00:00", "2012-06-30 01:00:00", "2012-07-31 01:00:00", 
"2012-08-31 01:00:00", "2012-09-30 01:00:00"), class = "data.frame")
```

It is Eurozone's CPI monthly time series.

Then an inflation estimate is

```
dinfl <- diff(log(infl))
```

I would like to get `dinfl` seasonality with the greatest possible accuracy; it's a stationary time series.

What would your suggestment be (model + package + function)?

Is there any chance of structural break which may require some analysis before? I remember something about `bfast()` package which allowed for structural break searching, I don't know if it could be useful here.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be fair, there is never a best model; they're all just simplifications of reality.  For seasonality decomposition, base `R` offers a couple powerful options: `decompose()` and `stl()`.  Here is the basics of how to apply it to your data:

```
infl.ts <- ts(infl$infl,start=c(2001,1),frequency=12)
plot(infl.ts)
plot(decompose(infl.ts,type='multiplicative'))
plot(stl(infl.ts,s.window='periodic'))
plot(stl(infl.ts,s.window=5))
```

`stl()` in particular is a very powerful decomposition technique with many parameters you can tune.  In the first call I used stationary seasonality (`s.window='periodic'`).  In the second one I used smoothing changing seasonality (`s.window=5`).  There are some details in the help documents (`?stl`) and the referenced scholarly articles have far more info.

Comment: I did just realize I forgot to `diff(log())` your data first.  Doing so does seem to improve the fit based on the 'remainder' panel of the `stl()` plot. (As it should.)

Comment: And I forgot to promote Rob Hyndman's excellent online resource: http://otexts.com/fpp/6/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Shea Parkes. Then I invite you to try `stl()` on my sample but considering just the observations starting from January 2009 till today: you will see a seasonal component which is much different from the one obtained by using `stl()` on the whole sample. Then I guess there must be some issue, like a structural break somewhere. Is it correct? `stl()` "sees" trend in differenced CPI time series, which should no be theoretically correct...

Comment: This is true, it does look for trend even if you pass it a diff'd time series.  If you wanted to use `stl()` it might make the most sense to just `log()` the series so it will look for multiplicative seasonality.  You're also right that there appears to be a structural break ~Jan-2009.  For my job, seeing is believing; I've never looked into formal structural break identifiers.

Comment: Yesterday I used `bfast()` package to search for structural breaks, and it found it about on 2008 ~ 2009; it is simple to use, it works like `stl()` but the output highlights structural breaks (it's slower, though). When I find a break in trend component I guess it would be better using `stl()` from that date on, also if the seasonal component does not show any break... correct?

Comment: I'm really not familiar with the `bfast` (package,function or method).  If it only locates breaks in trend/level, then I'd compare a few different estimates of seasonality using different methods and different time periods.  If `bfast` considered the likelihood of a seasonality break, then I assume it provides useful seasonality estimates as an output of its analysis.

Comment: Just another question, kind Shea Parkes: what could a good criterion to choose `s.window` value be? Let I have a monthly time series: is there any link between `s.window` argument and the frequency (which is equal to 12)? I've seen that setting `s.window` equal to 1 returns "zig-zag" extremes of loess trend component, while higher values smooth more. Are there any criteria to fit `s.window`? Thanks,